# Excel - Create an indented hierarchy list from a source data set

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an indented hierarchy list in Excel from a source data set.

The source data set has 3 levels (department, municipality and city).

I tried many different formula but honestly I cannot find the right system. Actually it's not even a matter of formula, what I'm missing here it's logic, honestly.

It would be easy to do it manually but since I have more 8000 rows it would be also  pretty time consuming.

This is the format of the source data:

[image]

And this is what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to proceed would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Stefano

Comment: A suggestion - do you **need** such a hierarchy? It could make doing any analysis/pivot tabling later a bit tricky.  Instead, when I need something like that, I do conditional formatting and just say "if a cell is equal to the one above, make the font WHITE". That way the duplicate values are "hidden", but still accessible if I need a `COUNTIF()`/`VLOOKUP()`/`Index/Match`/etc.

Comment: Thank you @BruceWayne for the idea, but actually yes, I need this type of hierarchy since I have to export the file to .csv and import it in a data collection software. I tried the "if a cell is equal to the one above, make the font WHITE" formula but what I can't do is to "stagger" (not sure if it's the right English word) the row like in the second picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a pivot table with your categories in the row field and any
   of them additionally as a data field.
2. Change the report layout to Outline form
3. Copy / Paste Values

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this with a pivot table...

[image]